# DataGridViewCell not updating until change the focus

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have this event for my DataGridView which is supposed to turn the CurrentCell.Value into null when delete key is pressed. Actually, it does work, but the value doesn't change until I change the selected/focused cell. How can I modify it in order to update instantly?

This is my code:

```
private void dataGridView1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Delete)
        {
            dataGridView1.CurrentCell.Value = null;
        }
        dataGridView1.RefreshEdit();
    }
```

Here's the entire designer code:

```
        this.dataGridView1.AllowDrop = true;
        this.dataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
        this.dataGridView1.AllowUserToDeleteRows = false;
        this.dataGridView1.AllowUserToResizeColumns = false;
        this.dataGridView1.AllowUserToResizeRows = false;
        this.dataGridView1.Anchor = ((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)((((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Top | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Bottom) 
        | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Left) 
        | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Right)));
        dataGridViewCellStyle1.Alignment = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
        dataGridViewCellStyle1.BackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.Control;
        dataGridViewCellStyle1.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 8.25F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
        dataGridViewCellStyle1.ForeColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.WindowText;
        dataGridViewCellStyle1.SelectionBackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent;
        dataGridViewCellStyle1.SelectionForeColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.WindowText;
        dataGridViewCellStyle1.WrapMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTriState.True;
        this.dataGridView1.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle = dataGridViewCellStyle1;
        this.dataGridView1.ColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode.AutoSize;
        dataGridViewCellStyle2.Alignment = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
        dataGridViewCellStyle2.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
        dataGridViewCellStyle2.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 8.25F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
        dataGridViewCellStyle2.ForeColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.ControlText;
        dataGridViewCellStyle2.SelectionBackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent;
        dataGridViewCellStyle2.SelectionForeColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.ControlText;
        dataGridViewCellStyle2.WrapMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTriState.False;
        this.dataGridView1.DefaultCellStyle = dataGridViewCellStyle2;
        this.dataGridView1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(86, 63);
        this.dataGridView1.MultiSelect = false;
        this.dataGridView1.Name = "dataGridView1";
        this.dataGridView1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(702, 372);
        this.dataGridView1.TabIndex = 6;
        this.dataGridView1.TabStop = false;
        this.dataGridView1.CellClick += new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventHandler(this.dataGridView1_CellClick);
        this.dataGridView1.CellEndEdit += new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventHandler(this.dataGridView1_CellEndEdit);
        this.dataGridView1.DragDrop += new System.Windows.Forms.DragEventHandler(this.dataGridView1_DragDrop);
        this.dataGridView1.DragOver += new System.Windows.Forms.DragEventHandler(this.dataGridView1_DragOver);
        this.dataGridView1.KeyUp += new System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventHandler(this.dataGridView1_KeyUp);
```

Comment: On a default dataGridview with 2 columns and 2 rows, this code works. I cannot re-produce the problem you describe. Tabbing to a cell and pressing delete clears the cell immediately.

Comment: Could you show us how you customized the dataGridView1? If you created it by designer show us a piece of designer generated code associated with the dataGridView1.

Comment: I added the designer code to the question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The answer was in the question. If the cell value only changes when it is not selected anymore, just deselect it.

```
private void dataGridView1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Delete)
        {
            dataGridView1.CurrentCell.Value = null;
            dataGridView1.CurrentCell.Selected = false;
        }
    }
```